# UI grid export to CSV with the result after filter?

Tags: csv, export, filtering, ng-grid

Im using ui-grid and I want to export to csv all the records after filter, anyone can help?
for example after filtering email is gmail.com I have 3 pages of records, how do I export to csv all the records from 3 pages?

Comment: Can you make the question a bit more specific? Are trying to export the data manually or using an API? If it's an API, can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: Im using ui-grid here is the code

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    /*plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin(csvOpts)],*/
    exporterMenuCsv: true,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    // pagingOptions -
    paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    enablePaginationControls: true,
    exporterFieldCallback: function( grid, row, col, input ) {
        if( col.name == 'user_name') {
            return $scope.getUserName(input);
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    },

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied filter to columnDefs, then you just have to write a callback method which will execute that same filter while exporting the data.

Below is my proposed solution. This method would work for multiple filter with multiple parameters.

Column defination:

```
var rptColumnDefs = [ {
        field: 'field1',
        cellFilter: "filter1:'param1' | filter2 | filter3 : 4 | filter4 : 4 : 'param2'",
        displayName: "Field 1"  
    }, field: 'field2',
        cellFilter: "filter1:'param1' | filter2 | filter3 : 4 | filter4 : 4 : 'param2'",
        displayName: "Field 2"  
    }]
```

Exporter Callback function:

```
$scope.reportGridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
    enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
    exporterCsvFilename: '',
    columnDefs: rptColumnDefs,    
    exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, input) {
            if (col.cellFilter) { // check if any filter is applied on the column
                var filters = col.cellFilter.split('|'); // get all the filters applied
                angular.forEach(filters, function (filter) {
                    var filterName = filter.split(':')[0]; // fetch filter name
                    var filterParams = filter.split(':').splice(1); //fetch all the filter parameters
                    filterParams.unshift(input); // insert the input element to the filter parameters list
                    var filterFn = $filter(filterName); // filter function
                    // call the filter, with multiple filter parameters. 
                    //'Apply' will call the function and pass the array elements as individual parameters to that function.
                    input = filterFn.apply(this, filterParams); 
                })
                return input;
            }
            else
                return input;
        }
}
```

This generic function will help export the data as it is displayed in UI Grid (after applying the filters.)

Comment: Did happen to set this up in a Plunker?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CSVExporter
{
    public static void WriteToCSV(List<Person> personList)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=PersonList.csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        WriteColumnName();
        foreach (Person person in personList)
        {
            WriteUserInfo(person);
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    private static void WriteUserInfo(Person person)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        AddComma(person.Name, stringBuilder);
        AddComma(person.Family, stringBuilder);
        AddComma(person.Age.ToString(), stringBuilder);
        AddComma(string.Format("{0:C2}", person.Salary), stringBuilder);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private static void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(value.Replace(',', ' '));
        stringBuilder.Append(", ");
    }

    private static void WriteColumnName()
    {
        string columnNames = "Name, Family, Age, Salary";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to do that in ui-gird not in server side
below is my code in ui-grid 
    $scope.exportCsv = function(){
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectAllRows();
        console.log(uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED);
        //$scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport(uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL);
        uiGridExporterService.csvExport($scope.gridApi.grid,uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL);
        //$scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
    };
but it doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: btw I don't know how to format code, how do you do that?